# HTML Table and TD Percentages Clarification

Tags: html, html-table, width

This is something that still somewhat confuses me.

Lets say I have code like this with a table width of 50%.

I then want 3 td's inside that table - would the TD's have to equal 100%?

My understanding is that 50% means 50% of the parent class so lets say a monitor is 1000 pixels - the table would be 500 pixels correct?

The 3 TD's within that table with a width of 33% would tally to be 500 pixels because the parent class is 50% of 1000 pixels - correct?

```
<table width="50%">
<tr>
<td width="33%">
<td width="33%">
<td width="33%">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

Latest updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/va6Lw1ec/1/

```
<div style="border:1px solid red" >
Start

<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">A</td>
    <td width="25%">B</td>
    <td width="75%">C</td>
  </tr>
</table>

End
</div>
```

And for your query "My understanding is that 50% means 50% of the parent class so lets say a monitor is 1000 pixels - the table would be 500 pixels correct?" 
See, If you are placing this table inside a DIV which occupies 25% of screen - then table within DIV will be half within the DIV

Can you give a pictorial representation what you need with HTML Table .
Also you can use **colspan** - attribute of HTML Table. (it will collate you columns in table)

Also you can get all simple samples in w3school.com

Comment: THanks for your response!  I just wanted verification in general - the width % always takes into consideration the PARENT element.

so lets say my screen is screen is 1000 pixels.

I have a div with a width of 50% - it would be 500 pixels

if I have a table inside the div with a width of 50% - the table would be 250 pixels

and if I had a td inside the table with a width of 50% - it would be 125 pixels correct?

Comment: See, As you know DIV is a container, it grows as the items fill in it.
table elements will be getting changed as you mentioned. I have updated the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/va6Lw1ec/1/ . Check the same. Hope you will get a clear picture

Comment: Got a downvote. Pls comment your reason too. that would be helpful